# How to complex update on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, crud, mongodb-query

I've got a question. My data is like this:

```
{
  "name" : "username",
  "surname" : "surname",
  "playlists": {
    "name": "playlistName",
    "date": "27-09-14",
    "musics": [
      "music name 1",
      "music name 2"
    ]
  },
  "playlists": {
    "name": "playlistName2",
    "date": "27-09-14",
    "musics": [
      "music name 1",
      "music name 2"
    ]
  }

}
```

I want to add one more "playlists" section to this data.
My data should be like this:

```
{
  "name" : "username",
  "surname" : "surname",
  "playlists": {
    "name": "playlistName",
    "date": "27-09-14",
    "musics": [
      "music name 1",
      "music name 2"
    ]
  },
  "playlists": {
    "name": "playlistName2",
    "date": "27-09-14",
    "musics": [
      "music name 1",
      "music name 2"
    ]
  },
  "playlists" : {
    "blabla" : "blabla"
  }

}
```

Update query didn't work. 
How do I? Thanks in advance. 
I trying

> $dbData = array('$set' => array('playlists' => array ('blabla' =>
>   'blabla'))); 
>       $users->update(array('_id' => new MongoId ('541f0e2216c8272c058b4567')),
>                 $dbData);

Comment: Show us some code. How are you trying to do this?

Comment: you mean you want add another playlist to one that exist in your data ?
or just want to add another array ?

Comment: its more easy to tell us what exactly do you need

Comment: I want to add array to existing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also it is possible to have multiple same keys, but it is not recommended (you have 2 `playlists` keys and want more).

One reasonable solution is to make `playlists` as an array and to push elements into it.

```
{
  "name" : "username",
  "surname" : "surname",
  "playlists": [...]
}

$dbData = array('$push' => array('playlists' => array ('blabla' => 'blabla'))); 
$users->update(array('_id' => new MongoId ('541f0e2216c8272c058b4567')), $dbData);
```